# Heroku Create hangs forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am new to RoR and just started learing few days back. I was creating some small apps & trying to deploy on heroku. Until yesterday everything went normal (Had few issues but could solve based on help from online). I am using ubuntu linux & Rails version is 3.0.9

When i give "heroku create" command on console, it hangs forever in creating application & never ends. I could able to create on yesterday & not sure what happened suddenly. when i look at logs

2011-07-03T07:17:52+00:00 heroku[api]: Add-on add logging:basic by xxxxx@xxxx.com

2011-07-03T07:17:52+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by xxxxx@xxxx.com

So nothing more than that (I have masked email id in logs for privacy).

heroku gem ( 2.3.6) was installed & also added ssh keys.

Does anyone have come across this in past? please suggest solution

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem.  For the last 30 minutes, I've been watching "....." being written across my terminal window, after I issued the 'heroku create' command for the first time.

After an hour, I hit Ctrl-C to kill the "...." being written across my screen.  Then I tried "heroku create" again, and it worked in under 5 seconds.

Comment: it seems some heroku issue. now i can create app. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try mentioning the application name after heroku create for instance: heroku create app-name

Comment: it seems some heroku issue. now i can create app.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli), `heroku` requires login first, so it's good idea to run this command first:

```
heroku login
```

I tried creating superuser on my app and I was asked to login on `heroku`: I opened the link that was offered to me, successfully logged in, but nothing happened in the console - I got stuck for a while. Why that happened - my guess is that `heroku client` did not receive the information that I am logged in. Because of that, I terminated the execution and I run the command for creating user again. It worked well from that point - I was offered to create the user.